# Bluemix - Failed to get plug-in : Looking up 'container-service' from repository 'Bluemix'

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, kubernetes

I was trying to install newest Bluemix container service with Kubenetes plug-in; however, I got below message. Followed by [DOC - container service](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_cli_install.html#cs_cli_install)

```
ocmbpro:~ ochen$ bx plugin install container-service -r Bluemix
Looking up 'container-service' from repository 'Bluemix'...
FAILED
'Bluemix' does not exist as an available plug-in repo. Check the name and try again.
```

[Error_msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LK4o.png)

Has anyone met this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the plugin binary directly here:

https://clis.ng.bluemix.net/ui/repository.html#bluemix-plugins

Then run `bx plugin install ~/Downloads/my-plugin`.

---

You could run this command to add `Bluemix` to your list of available repos:

```
bx plugin repo-add Bluemix https://plugins.ng.bluemix.net
```

After that, when you list your repos, it should be there:

```
$ bx plugin repos
Listing added plug-in repositories...

Repo Name   URL
Bluemix     https://plugins.ng.bluemix.net
```

Then you can list the plugins:

```
$ bx plugin repo-plugins
Getting plug-ins from all repositories...

Repository: Bluemix
Name                      Description                                                                                                                                                  Versions
active-deploy             Bluemix CLI plugin for Active Deploy to help you update applications and containers with no downtime. Works for Cloud Foundry apps and for IBM Containers.   0.1.97, 0.1.105
auto-scaling              Bluemix CLI plug-in for Auto-Scaling service                                                                                                                 0.2.1, 0.2.2
vpn                       Bluemix CLI plug-in for IBM VPN service                                                                                                                      1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2
private-network-peering   pnp-plugin-description                                                                                                                                       0.1.1
IBM-Containers            Plugin to operate IBM Containers service                                                                                                                     1.0.0
container-registry        Plugin for IBM Bluemix Container Registry.                                                                                                                   0.1.104, 0.1.107
container-service         IBM Bluemix Container Service for management of Kubernetes clusters                                                                                          0.1.217
sdk-gen                   Plugin to generate SDKs from Open API specifications                                                                                                         0.1.1
dev                       IBM Bluemix CLI Developer Plug-in                                                                                                                            0.0.5
```

Then you can install one:

```
bluemix plugin install plugin_name -r Bluemix
```

Comment: Hi @owhc, did this answer your question?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Something is wrong with IBM's website.